# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Tags: php, object, upload, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make an image uploader, but it always give me this error

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

here is my code controller code

```
public function uploadImageProcess(){

    $destinatonPath = '';
    $filename = '';

    $file = Input::file('image');
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/assets/images/';
    $filename = str_random(6).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        $images = new Images;

        $images->title = Input::get('title');
        $images->path = '/assets/images/' . $filename;
        $image->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        Session::flash('success_insert','<strong>Upload success</strong>');
        return Redirect::to('user/dashboard');
    }
}
```

and here is the upload form

```
<form role="form" action="{{URL::to('user/poster/upload_process')}}" method="post">
    <label>Judul Poster</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title">
    <label>Poster</label>
    <input class="" type="file" name="image"><br/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >
</form>
```

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You miss `enctype` attribute in your form markup.

Either do this

```
<form role="form" action="{{URL::to('user/poster/upload_process')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

or this...

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/poster/upload_process', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post')) }}
// ...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

These code are right, but you didn't check values of returns of `Input::file('image')`. I think returns value may be is not a correct object or your class Input does not have a public function name is `getClientOriginalName`.

Code:

```
$file = Input::file('image');
var_dump($file); // if return a correct object. you will check your class Input.
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, the result is NULL
so, how i can get the input file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is just because you forget to write `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` tag.

This error happen just when you forget this:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('articles.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Form 'files'=> true
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['Please Type Url'], 'class' => 'form-horizontal' ,  ***'files' => true***]) !!}

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/xyz','files' => true)) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You may want to add an explanation to your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Laravel Collective than you can try this solution

```php
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/poster/upload_process', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

else if you are using html form tag than you have to put extra markdown for storing image data

```html
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('user/poster/upload_process') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```